# How to fix mysql create table error, ERROR 1030 (HY000): Got error 168 from storage engine

Tags: mysql, innodb

I try to create a new MySQL table,

```
CREATE TABLE test 
     (user_id BIGINT) ;
```

It failed and pop-up the error message:

```
ERROR 1030 (HY000): Got error 168 from storage engine
```

I checked the MySQL error logs, it shows me the reason:

```
[Warning] InnoDB: Tablespace 'test_db/test' exists in the cache with id 1271659 != 1271713
```

try again,error logs:

```
[Warning] InnoDB: Tablespace 'test_db/test' exists in the cache with id 1271659 != 1271714
```

anyone can tell me how to fix it.

Comment: Have you checked you don't already have a table called test? (type describe test)

Comment: Sounds like some kind of corruption.  Check the logs.